# How to perform bidirectional filtering when SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR() requires contiguous dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a created a calendar table in my data model in order to calculate the sum of total units compared to the previous year.

[image]

Everything works fine, however, because it's a single directional filter when I click on a particular school, it does not filter calendar table to only the years which has data.

[image]

[image]

I then tried to change the relationship so that it has bidirectional filtering to allow me to click on a school which should filter the years from the calendar table but I run into this error for my current year vs previous year visual:

[image]

**DAX Code:**

```
Amount PY = CALCULATE(
    SUM(XXXX[TotalUnits]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calender Table'[Date]))
```

My question is, how do I go about doing a bidirectional filter so I can select a school and filter the dates, as the DAX code I am using needs contiguous dates so it does not allow me to change the cross filter direction?

Comment: Is the School column a part of dimension table or a fact table? Can you share the image of whole model.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant show the entire model, however, it is just a normal dimension table which the calender table is linked to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

Create a measure to check if the table is not empty using:

```
Check = 
INT(NOT ISEMPTY(tablename))
```

Then add this measure as a filter for that specific visual and make it show items when the value returns `1`.

Now when the school is selected, the date filter now filters to show only the years which has data for it.